# capturing bubbling key event from flash with javascript?

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3, internet-explorer

In IE, if flash has focus, and receives a keydown event, it does not appear to bubble the event up through the DOM (I can't capture the event by listening on document, however the same listener can capture key events from html siblings, so I know my listener is working).

However, some other plugins on the page (I am looking at you windows media player) still respond to key events that initiate in flash (and I need to prevent that from happening)! It seems that the key event initiated in flash takes the bubble express highway straight to the top (where the top is whatever is above document in the DOM hierarchy).

I have tried terminating the events in as3, and tried different wmodes... neither approach works. Is there something I might have missed?

Comment: Does it also fail with `keyup`?

Comment: By then it is too late; the other plugin has already acted on the keydown.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this problem?? I have the same one.

Comment: @AgileJedi Sorry fellow Jedi, I could find no solution.

Answer (score 0):

Focus just the `swf` container :

```
document.getElementById('flash-object').focus();
```